# Using Braintree Dropin UI "braintree is not defined"

Tags: javascript, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am attempting to follow the basics of Braintree integration and I am running into stumbling block after stumbling block seeing the flow in action.

Right now I am trying to take a look at the dropin UI for Braintree and using their code, copy and pasted I am running into

> "braintree is not defined"

when the braintree.dropin.create is executed.

```
<div id="dropin-container"></div>
<button id="submit-button">Purchase</button>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.14.1/js/dropin.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

  braintree.dropin.create({
    authorization: 'CLIENT_AUTHORIZATION',
    container: '#dropin-container'
  }, function (err, dropinInstance) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle any errors that might've occurred when creating Drop-in
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      dropinInstance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
        if (err) {
          // Handle errors in requesting payment method
        }

        // Send payload.nonce to your server
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to get this dropin working?

Edit:
As far as development stack is concerned I am creating this in a Django environment and testing with both the JavaScript library and the Python library. This particular implementation I am attempting to use the javascript library.

Comment: What server-side language are you using? Have you included the braintree library?

_Full disclosure: I work for Braintree. Feel free to reach out to Support_ https://help.braintreepayments.com

Comment: @turaco I updated the above post. I am trying to use JavaScript library and the Python Library. I will try adding the JavaScript library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own issue by starting over and using this code:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v3

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.14.1/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dropin-container"></div>
  <button id="submit-button">Request payment method</button>
  <script>
    var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

    braintree.dropin.create({
      authorization: 'CLIENT_TOKEN_FROM_SERVER',
      container: '#dropin-container'
    }, function (createErr, instance) {
      button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
          // Submit payload.nonce to your server
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

I then provided the CLIENT_TOKEN_FROM_SERVER via the Python Library. Works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and moved the code for dropin.create to happen once the page was loaded and problem went away